# Is "capabalize" a correct verb?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I've just came up with a verb "**capabalize**" as a synonym for enable.

> It's main intention is to capabalize / enable the system for...

Is it correct? I could not find it in several dictionaries.

Comment: While it's true that no dictionary of English can ever be complete (because of productive affixes and neologisms), and therefore absence of evidence in a dictionary is not evidence of absence .... I'd say no, I don't think anyone has used the word "capabalize". Not only is it not listed in any dictionary indexed by OneLook.com, there are precisely zero hits for it in the COCA corpus.

Comment: It would be spelled *capabilize* if it existed (compare *capability*).

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing this word, and I would find it awkward and off-putting to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you're looking for is capabilitate: To make capable; to indicate the capabilities of a property.

The source is OED2 (book).

Comment: You have a source, so I believe you.  Does the OED give a example of usage?  Is there a nuance for this word that differentiates it from enable?  Maybe more work than you signed up for, but this is a strange word for me!

Comment: @ab2 The OED marks this *obs*; the only example given is "1780   W. Woty in Cussans *Hist. Herts* 104   Brown..whom Chambers may excel, But ne'er could capabilitate so well."

Comment: +1, also http://www.thefullwiki.org/capabilitate